# How to change my error handling method

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I can't seem to get my head around why people say C++ exceptions are better. For example, I have an application which loads function objects from shared objects to be used in the application. What goes on is something like this:

```
bool LoadFunctions()
{
   //Get Function factory.
   FunctionFactory& oFactory = GetFunctionFactory();
   //Create functions from the factory and use.
}

FunctionFactory& GetFunctionFactory()
{
   //Get shared object handle.
   void* pHandle = dlopen("someso.so");

   //Get function ptr for Factory getter.
   typedef FunctionFactory* (*tpfFacGet)();
   tpfFacGet pF = static_cast<tpfFacGet>(dlsym(pHandle, "GetFactory"));

   //Call function and return object.
   return *((*pF)());
}
```

Now, it's easy to see that loads of stuff can go wrong. If I did it like I always do, I'd return pointers instead of references, and I'd check if they were `NULL` and print an error message and get out if they weren't. That way, I know where things went wrong and I can even try to recover from that (i.e. If I successfully load the factory and fail to load just a single function, I may still continue). What I don't understand is how to use exceptions in such a scenario and how to recover the program rather than printing an error message and qutting. Can someone tell me how I am to do this in C++ish way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't even need return codes.  If a problem occurs it should be in the exception.

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        LoadFunctions();
        // if we're here, everything succeeded!
    }
    catch(std::exception _e)
    {
        // output exception message, quit gracefully
    } 

    // IRRESPECTIVE OF SUCCESS/FAILURE WE END UP HERE

    return 0;
} // eo main
```

EDIT:

Okay, so lets say that you have an alternative method of loading functions should `LoadFunctions()` fail.  You might be tempted to call that in the `catch` handler, but this way you'll quickly end up with a huge amount of nested exception handlers which just complicates things.

So now we get down to the question of *design*.  `LoadFunctions` should succeed if functions are loaded and throw out an exception if it does not.  In this hypothetical example of an alternative method of loading functions, that call should be within the `LoadFunctions` method.  This alternative method does not need to be visible to the caller.

At the top level we either end up with functions, or we do not.  Writing good exception handling, **in my opinion** is about getting rid of grey areas.  The function did what it was told to do, or it didn't.

Comment: "// output exception message, quit gracefully" - This is exactly the kind of thing I don't understand. What if I don't want to quit? What do I do then?

Comment: If you don't want to quit, just write what you want to do instead in the catch block.

Comment: It is that easy, and then you know that your GetFunctionFactory functions always returns a consistent results, eliminating the need of checking it every time it is used.

Comment: @Simone : What scope would be visible to me? And where would I be continuing from. (when/after) I hit the catch block? What if the problem was in a deeply nested function?

Comment: You can access the catch-block's local variables and the block outside the try-block's ones. After the catch-block, you end up in **return 0;** in this example

Comment: @nakiya, as I've just edited my post to say, That top level function succeeds, or it does not.  I would expect those deeply nested functions to throw an exception if they go wrong too.  Right at the top-level, we know if something went wrong and we've done this without a plethora of complicated return codes from 15 little functions that might get called during this.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: I can exit gracefully, but I'll be left with nothing. Not even a dump file because I catch the exception and return. And no knowledge of what happened because anything that might have gone wrong is nested deeply and is caught by a top-level try-catch block which doesnt know what this is about.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the exception that is thrown carries the necessary information WITH it.  And far more verbosely than an error code.

Answer (score 0):

There is, as you say, a lot that can go wrong. You won't catch a bad cast there by the way. If the symbol exists but is not the type you are casting it to, you will just get a nasty shock later.

If you were to avoid exceptions you will need somewhere to report the error. As your LoadFunctions and GetFunctionFactory() do not know how you wish to handle the error (log it? print it to stderr? Put up a message box?) The only thing it can do is generate the error.

A common way do to that in C is to pass in a parameter into which it can put the error if one occurs, and for each function to "check" success before continuing. This can make the flow rather tricky.

The C++ concept of "throwing" the exception means that you do not need to keep passing a pointer (or reference) through each function. Where the error occurs you generate it and "throw" it - a bit like "shouting" it. This causes all code (other than cleanup in destructors) to halt until it finds a catcher that handles the error the way that is required.

Note that exceptions should only generally be used to handle errors, not a normal occurrence like encountering "end of file" when this is the way you know a read has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Using exceptions instead of return-values (or any other method) is not supposed to change the behaviour of the code, only how it is written and organized. That means basically that first you decide what your recovery of a certain error is, be it more graceful or less, then you write the code to perform that.
Most experienced programmers (all practically) agree that exceptions are a much better method than return values. You can't see the big difference in short examples of a few functions, but in real systems of thousands of functions and types you would see it clearly. I will not get into more details of how it is better.
I suggest anyway you should just get yourself used to using exceptions by default. However note that using exceptions has some somewhat delicate issues (e.g. RAII http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII), that ultimately make your code better, but you should read about them in a book (I won't be able to describe here and feel that I do justice to the subject).
I think the book "Effective c++ / Scott Meyer" deals with that, certainly "Exceptional C++ / Herb Sutter". These books are a good jump start for any c++ developer if you havent read them anyway.